# Problems with firebase logic

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problems and I'm pretty sure people here can help me.

I'm a beginner in coding (1 or 2 month only) and I have a big difficulty to figured how the logic work.

Here's my problems:

I have 3 collections in firebase:

1. Tournament
2. Tour
3. Notes

-> I have multiple tournament, everyone contain 5 different tours and each tournament contain note take by user.

So my problems is, how can I related theses 3 collections and show only example:

Tournament A -> Tour: A, B, C, D, E -> User notes for every tournament?

I just need help on how I need to think to group everything.

Comment: Are you using Firestore or realtime database

Comment: I'm using firestore!

Comment: I think i found the best solution!

Comment: Sure.. go ahead. let me know if you need anything

Comment: If I create 3 collections with the same document id! Do you think that would work??

Comment: please see the link for the database -1. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JQ2KcSWp4rMZzJRm_u7--RrDGZ5F8sOQ -----
2.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=18Vv021dXt41xxf2-tE8cYDEGBm3EwsJ9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single correct data model, as (with all NoSQL solutions) the best data model depends on the use-cases of your app.

But as far as I can see, you have two major options:

1. Nest the child collections
2. Connect documents by embedding parent IDs

## Nest the child collections

Firestore is a database that contains collections of documents. Each document can contain subcollections under it. Given that your data model is hierarchical, that means you can nest them like this:

```
Tournaments (collection)
  Tournament1 (document)
    Tours (collection)
      Tour1_1 (document)
        Notes (collection)
          Notes1_1_1 (document)
```

Now each tournament has its own tours, and each tour has its own notes. You can access them in isolation: so just read the notes for a single tour, without needing to build a query for that.

## Connect documents by embedding parent IDs

The alternative is to have three top-level collections, and to connect each child document to its parent by embedding the parent ID into it, like this:

```
Tournaments (collection)
  Tournament1 (document)
Tours (collection)
  Tour1_1 (document)
    TournamentID: Tournament1
Notes (collection)
  Notes1_1_1 (document)
    TourID: Tour1_1
```

With this model you can get all Tours for a Tournament by querying `ref.collection("Tours").where("TournamentID", "==", "Tournament1")`.

An advantage of the second model is that you can access tours across all tournaments, while in the first model you can only access the tours for one tournament at a time (at least until Firestore implements collection group queries).

A disadvantage of the second model is that you'll always need to query, and that it is less scaleable as far as writes are concerned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I think the second options is the best for me.